# Linux backup script "file changed as we read it"

Tags: linux, bash, backup

I have been having a fiddle with a backup script posted on 
[Github](https://github.com/todiadiyatmo/bash-backup-rotation-script/blob/master/backup_rotation.sh)
 The script uses tar. The files I wish to be backed up include folders/files that are being written/read continously. I wish for the script to take a backup anyway of the "image" of the file at the time of the script running and passing over the point.

I have included --ignore-failed-read but the issue still exists.

My slightly edited part of the script looks like:

```
# Compress tables and files
cd "$TARGET_DIR"
tar -czf "$BACKUP_DIR/backup.incoming/$backup_filename" --ignore-failed-read -C "$BACKUP_DIR/backup.incoming/" --exclude "$BACKUP_DIR" mysql_dump.sql "$TARGET_DIR"
```

Thanks

Comment: You mean you know the reason of the error and want to just ignore it?

Comment: I want the backup to include the directories and not skip them

Comment: What do you want the script to do with the file that changes? It can't just "backup the old version" or "ignore the change and keep reading the new file" so what do you want it to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If disk space is not an issue, you may want to create a copy using rsync first, e.g.:

```
rsync -a --exclude="$BACKUP_DIR" \
    "$BACKUP_DIR/backup.incoming/$TARGET_DIR" \
    "$BACKUP_DIR/backup.rsync"
```

After that, running `tar` against the rsync copy should not trigger similar error. By default rsync would just adding files, if you want the deleted files (from the src dir) also removed from the rsync copy, option `--delete` can be used.

Comment: This does not solve the issue. Instead you suppress the "file changed" warning as rsync does not check for file corruption while transfers. If you really want to solve this with rsync, you would need to use `--checksum` or execute it in a loop until rsync does not transfer files anymore.